# Magento 2.4.0 stock status not changed after 0 quantity in multi source inventory

Tags: stock-status, magento2.4.0, multi-source-inventory

I added two inventory source location in Magento 2.4.0 to manage different warehouse inventory. And
also I added two different website.

**For example**

One warehouse is Canada and another warehouse in USA. Both locations have different quantity.

Canada has 50 and USA has 100. I set 0 qty for Canada warehouse and save the product. Product stock status still showing `IN STOCK` and also set 0 zero qty for USA warehouse and still showing in stock status and when I visit at front product showing out of stock message, how? this is default functionality of Magento

Note: I am running magento 2.4.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign your Warehouse to the store's inventory to link your product stock?

**Steps to Reproduce**

- check your store's inventory source (the warehouse to be linked). E.g. store inventory should implement Magento Multi-source inventory to create sources, stocks, and track products.
- Assign the Sales channel (your website) to manage the inventory stock.
- Did you assign sources for each product in the product edit page and even define product quantity in each source?
- Save the product and check the status where the product source is linked.

These are some steps that might help you to configure and manage product stock. If not resolved, please confirm then.

Comment: I think you did not understand the question.